# How do I get the last value of a CQL list column?

Tags: cassandra, cql, scylla

I'm using scylladb lists ( https://docs.scylladb.com/stable/cql/types.html#lists ). I created a same table from documentation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE plays (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    game text,
    players int,
    scores list<int> // A list of integers
);
```

After creating the table, I inserted the data using query:

```sql
INSERT INTO plays (id, game, players, scores)
           VALUES ('123-afde', 'quake', 3, [17, 4, 24241414]);
```

How do i get only last score `24241414` from table, instead of getting full list of scores? I need CQL-query (operator).

Query `SELECT scores FROM plays WHERE id = '123-afde'`
returns full list. It's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting an element by index (at a particular position) of a CQL `list` is not supported by the CQL grammar because its performance can be unpredictable as discussed in [CASSANDRA-7396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7396).

You will need to implement it in your app by getting the size/length of the list    then use that value to calculate the last index position. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: Erick, you're right that getting an element at a specific position in the list - e.g., the 3rd element - would not have O(1) performance, but in fact getting the **last** element of a list would be. But Cassandra doesn't have a syntax for that. Please also note that for several reasons, both Scylla and Cassandra discourage large lists, and if your list is small then fetching the full list is usually "good enough" and would have almost the same performance as fetching just its last element.